# sequelize: How to count a select subquery

Tags: mariadb, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-cli, sequelize-typescript

I dont know how to create a non-raw query using sequelize like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(res.id)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        clients.id,
        COUNT(client_addresses.id) AS total_client_addresses
    FROM
        clients
    LEFT OUTER JOIN client_addresses ON clients.id = client_addresses.client_id
    GROUP BY
        clients.id
    HAVING
        total_client_addresses > 0
) as res
```

Any suggestions for my query ?

Comment: First, you must understand that `COUNT(x)` counts how many `x` are non-NULL.  Is that what you need?

Comment: Sequelize is about simple aggregating queries only it's mostly about CRUD operations

Comment: Why a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` when you apply a `HAVING` crtieria to exclude no maps, and like @RickJames said, a null `client-address.id` from the join isn't counted. So the query you are after is how many clients with at least one address?

Comment: Ok, let's suppose changing using a simple JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN and continuing changing total_client_addresses > 0 by total_client_addresses > 5. How can I do that using sequelize in a non-raw query, entirely with entities models? 

Comment: I come from ruby on rails using kaminari gem that is useful for records pagination , but using typescript with nestjs I can barely switch it up with sequelize.  What I need to do is paginate my records with my own count calculation. That is what I wanted to do without success.

Comment: After looking for on the Internet I realized that it can be solved with a full raw query without complex model association query thanks a lot to you all.